# Facebook login - LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions never trigger callback

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have followed every steps in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/

I implmented using pretty straightforward way

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onActivityResult " + requestCode);

    ...
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

CallbackManager callbackManager;

private void facebook() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onSuccess");
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();


            if (accessToken != null) {
                Log.i("CHEOK", "*token --> " + accessToken.getToken());
                Log.i("CHEOK", "*date --> " + accessToken.getExpires());
            } else {
                Log.i("CHEOK", "*no access token");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "Error " + error);
        }
    });


    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
            this,
            Arrays.asList("email")
    );
}
```

[image]

---

However, I

1. Never receive any callback in `CallbackManager`
2. Code in `onActivityResult` not seem to be executed
3. Didn't see any error log in Android Studio console

May I know what's wrong, and how I can debug this issue?

p/s Note, when the progress dialog of Facebook being dismiss (By pressing back button), I will receive `onActivityResult` and `FacebookCallback`'s `onCancel` called.

```
onActivityResult 64206
onCancel
```

Comment: By Any chance the network  you are currently using is Restricted Facebook domain ?

Comment: No. My current network is fast, and doesn't block any facebook thingy.

Comment: updated my answer , check now , i have used the graph request for login , let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Declare a Facebook login button in `xml` and make it `visibility` to `gone` and declare in java class also with click listener

xml file

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/flogin_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

`Activity` or `fragment` class

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginButton flogin_button;
```

in **onCreate()**

```
 flogin_button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.flogin_button);
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

// facebook login button click listener
login_facebook_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        // App code
        Log.e("onSuccess", "--------" + loginResult.getAccessToken());
        Log.e("Token", "--------" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
        Log.e("Permision", "--------" + loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        Log.e("ProfileDataNameF", "--" + profile.getFirstName());
        Log.e("ProfileDataNameL", "--" + profile.getLastName());

        Log.e("Image URI", "--" + profile.getLinkUri());

        Log.e("OnGraph", "------------------------");
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        Log.e("GraphResponse", "-------------" + response.toString());
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
          parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.type(large)");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code
    }
});
```

and **onActivityResult()**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onActivityResult " + requestCode);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

> and Finally do this when you want to do facebook login

```
flogin_button.performClick();
```

**NOTE:-**

> 1) SHOULD HAVE DECLARED CORRECT FACEBOOK KEY IN PROJECT.
>
> 2) APP SHOULD BE LIVE IN FACEBOOK CONSOLE.
>
> 3) SHOULD HAVE ADDED CORRECT SHA KEY IN FACEBOOK (debug/release)